# Is it possible to send an email via api to a google group for work?

Tags: gmail-api

I would like to insert an email via gmail api to a group, in the same way it's possible with the Gmail api Users.messages.insert (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert)

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your subject says you are trying to "send" an email but the question says your trying to insert it into the group (for archiving).

If you want to add a message to the group archive, use [the Groups Migration API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/get-start/getting-started).

If you want to send a message to the group so that all members of the group get the message, authenticate as a Gmail user who has rights to send to the group and use [messages.send()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending).